# is it possible to miss push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

We have an Azure server which sends push notifications.

I implemented GCM in the Android app. Some activities should handle specific notifications, others shouldn't.

So I register the receiver in onresume, and unregister in onpause. They are called, but sometimes, I miss the notification: it just doesn't arrive. Also not when switching of wifi / 3g and on again...

Is it possible dat a push notification is missed this way?
When I register in the onCreate and unregister in the onDestroy, it seems ok.

Comment: Please include your code. Do you mean you register the broadcast receiver that handles the GCM messages in code? Why not do it in the manifest? And un-registering when the app leaves the foreground defeats the main purpose of GCM (which is to receive notifications from the server when your app is not running).

Comment: we need the push notifications to have 2 users to synchronize. They both need to enter information, confirm this. When the server then accepts the information from both, they will be notified and thus can proceed to the next screen. So it is not a general notification, but specific per situation / activity